# change title background with html tag chart.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, chart.js

Ive been trying to change the background color of the chart.js title.
[image: chart]

Ive searched for any options within the title config to change it but there is no option. The next thing i tried was adding html to the ctx.

```
this.boxes[1].ctx.innerHTML = '<div class="sect-h"></div>';
```

This also doesnt seem to work. There is no callback function in title i can use. So i dont really know what i can try anymore.

All i want is to wrap a class "sect-h" around my title so it has a different background color.

Comment: Can you not look up what kind of tag / class / id the title has and just apply css to it?

Comment: You can only specify the properties stated on [documentation](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/title.html). Chart.js is a canvas-based chart library, so there are no sub-elements to whom you could add styles via CSS

Comment: The suggestion is to avoid using chart.js title configuration and add your own HTML title.